# Permissions denied with the docker volumes folder when using rails CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, docker

I started a RoR project. I use docker to easily install what I need (database, external tools...). In the root of my project, I've got a `data` folder containing all the docker volumes. The issue is when I run `rails generate controller X`, I don't know why but rails wants to access to the `data` folder (which is completely useless) and so, I have a **permission denied** for the `data` folder;

```
ruby-2.5.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:192:in `initialize': Permission denied @ dir_initialize - /home/mcdostone/X/Y/data/pgadmin/storage/root (Errno::EACCES)
from ruby-2.5.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:192:in `new'


ll -ah  /home/mcdostone/X/Y/data/
total 16K

drwxr-xr-x     4   root              root    4.0K Aug 21 10:52   ./
drwxr-xr-x    17   mcdostone   mcdostone     4.0K Aug 21 12:59   ../
drwxr-xr-x     4   root              root    4.0K Aug 21 10:54   pgadmin/
drwx------    19   999               root    4.0K Aug 21 10:52   postgres/
```

Any idea to avoid that unless changing the folder's permissions ? I don't want to break my containers.

Comment: what do you see when you do this 'ls -lh /home/mcdostone/X/Y'

Comment: I know I don't have the permissions to explore thoses folders, this is normal but I don't understand why rails needs to access to these folders, I hope there is a configuration to change to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible solutions for this problem:

1. Simply move the directory into the parent directory.
2. Change your Docker setup so that it uses the same user id that your host system uses (you can control this on some images via environment variables)
3. The gem `rb-inotify` cannot exclude properly. It is [a known (but closed) issue (48)](https://github.com/guard/rb-inotify/issues/48). So you could fix / add the behaviour so that folders with permission errors will be simply ignored or that you can control ignored folders. I'm sure they will happily accept a PR.